# getting node to work in cygwin

Tags: windows, node.js

I am trying to get node to work in cygwin and I am struggling...

Path where cygwin is installed `C:\cygwin64`

Path where node is stored (windows install version)`C:\Program Files\nodejs`

**CYGWIN**

```
$ node --version
v0.10.28
$ npm --version
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: line 2: $'\r': command not found
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: line 4: $'\r': command not found
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `$'in\r''
'cygdrive/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: line 5: `case `uname` in
```

**Windows CMD**

```
>node --version
v0.10.28
>npm --version
1.4.9
```

I then **uninstalled** node and I tried to build it in cygwin using the windows method [here](http://howtonode.org/how-to-install-nodejs). But I am having trouble with the `./configure` and `make` parts below. what am i doing wrong?

**./configure:**

```
$ ./configure
ctrpp not found in WinSDK path--using pre-gen files from tools/msvs/genfiles.
{ 'target_defaults': { 'cflags': [],
                       'default_configuration': 'Release',
                       'defines': ['OPENSSL_NO_SSL2=1'],
                       'include_dirs': [],
                       'libraries': []},
  'variables': { 'clang': 0,
                 'gcc_version': 48,
                 'host_arch': 'x64',
                 'node_install_npm': 'true',
                 'node_prefix': '',
                 'node_shared_cares': 'false',
                 'node_shared_http_parser': 'false',
                 'node_shared_libuv': 'false',
                 'node_shared_openssl': 'false',
                 'node_shared_v8': 'false',
                 'node_shared_zlib': 'false',
                 'node_tag': '',
                 'node_use_dtrace': 'false',
                 'node_use_etw': 'true',
                 'node_use_mdb': 'false',
                 'node_use_openssl': 'true',
                 'node_use_perfctr': 'true',
                 'python': '/usr/bin/python',
                 'target_arch': 'x64',
                 'uv_library': 'static_library',
                 'v8_enable_gdbjit': 0,
                 'v8_enable_i18n_support': 0,
                 'v8_no_strict_aliasing': 1,
                 'v8_optimized_debug': 0,
                 'v8_random_seed': 0,
                 'v8_use_snapshot': 'true'}}
creating  ./config.gypi
creating  ./config.mk
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:\Users\User Name/.gyp
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Users/User Name/.gyp
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
```

**make:**

```
$ make
/usr/bin/python tools/gyp_node.py -f make
make -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=1
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/User Name/node/out'
Makefile:271: *** mixed implicit and normal rules.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/User Name/node/out'
Makefile:45: recipe for target 'node' failed
make: *** [node] Error 2
```

NOTE: I have found similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297422/trouble-with-starting-node-js-from-a-cygwin-console) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043177/node-js-cygwin-not-supported) but no soltution not for the lack of trying :(

Comment: Cygwin support was dropped a long time ago. So stop trying to make it work. Even if it does there is no knowing what could be broken.

Comment: Why are you trying to use cygwin anyways? The windows port of node.js runs just fine. If you're trying to develop for linux specifically (maybe filesystem specific?), you're way better off running a Virtual Machine instead.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that ./configure grabs the OS type and tries to pull in Windows SDK utilities. You can get further if you force the OS type to linux:

```
./configure --dest-os linux
```

Unfortunately this gets you part of the way there. `make` starts to work, but fails because cygwin doesn't have a thread barrier implementation:

```
g++ [...] ../deps/debugger-agent/src/agent.cc
In file included from ../deps/uv/include/uv.h:61:0,
             from ../deps/debugger-agent/include/debugger-agent.h:25,
             from ../deps/debugger-agent/src/agent.cc:23:
../deps/uv/include/uv-unix.h:152:9: error: "pthread_barrier_t" does not name a type
```

sniff :(

Answer (score 0):

### Getting `npm` in cygwin

I was trying to get `npm` commands to run, then discovered that the `node -v` command was working out of the box, but not `npm -v`. After having a dig around I discovered that this command works inside cygwin:

```bash
node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" -v
```

If you happen to be using [justfiles](https://github.com/casey/just) like me, the most ergonomic way I've found to use it is something like this:

```
npm := 'node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"'
npx := 'node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npx-cli.js"'

npm-version:
 {{npm}} -v

build package:
 cd ./packages/{{package}} && {{npm}} run build
```