# How to open a node REPL in emacs?

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

I'm going through the Coursera Startup Engineering course offered by Stanford. The assignment is asking me to open a node REPL within emacs by using the command C-c!.  I don't seem to be able to use the '!' that it requires.

The instructor first has me using C-x 3 to split the buffer into two pieces. Then we are to use C-c! but I can't get it to work.

I have tried Ctrl-C -> Shift-! and I get the error message:
C-c ! is undefined

I have tried enter the '!' while still holding C-c and also to use the meta key with no luck.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Could it be a problem with my keybindings?

Link to the tutorial video: https://class.coursera.org/startup-001/lecture/173

Comment: Emacs doesn't have a REPL for NodeJS out of the box. Are you using [`nodejs-repl`](https://github.com/abicky/nodejs-repl.el)? Something else?

Comment: I don't think Emacs supports this out of the box. Your instructor is probably using an add-on package, and should be giving you instructions on how to do the same. Alternatively, perhaps they are using an Emacs distribution that comes with such a package bundled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check whether .emacs is present using the command " ls -la .emacs "
2. If it is present use "mv .emacs old.emacs"

This should solve your problem, for some more solutions regarding the same problem, check the thread

https://class.coursera.org/startup-001/forum/thread?thread_id=3013

Answer (score 1):

The C-c keymap is generally mode-specific, so the missing step is that you're probably not in the right mode.  The footnote he has mentions the "comint-mode" feature.  when we loads fibonocci.js, he's just in Javascript mode, does the C-x 3, and then uses a keybinding that isn't present by default.

There's some info at [how to run node.js interactively in Emacs on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909836/how-to-run-node-js-interactively-in-emacs-on-windows).  You probably don't have to use that however.

Your instructor has some code in his ~/.emacs - pulled in from a class Github repo - that should be shared with students.  It's probably a good idea to review his lecture segment "Emacs: Installation" in 4b.

git clone https://github.com/startup-class/setup.git
(the script in there calls "git clone https://github.com/startup-class/dotfiles.git" too)

It looks like he has a fondness for putting ".sh" on the end of shell scripts.  Be warned that this is incorrect for shell scripts used as commands, since it unnecessarily exposes an implementation detail, breaking a sort of encapsulation.

Comment: Thank your for the ".sh" tip. That's something I've never thought about.