# Slow Mac when sending input to an inferior python process

Tags: python, macos, emacs

Update: This does not hold for R's inferior ESS process on Mac, but of course I'm here interested in Python.

More updates: It just seems the buffer is slow for evaluating newlines.

Whenever I evaluate (send text) to the inferior buffer, it is extremely slow to send and render the text in the inferior buffer. You can literally see it write the `...` for each single line. So imagine having a 100 line function, that would take a while (note: the actual execution of the function is no problem, just the writing lines to the buffer is).

What would be the variable to change for this?

Try:

```
def uselessfunction():
    a = 1
    a = 1
    a = 1
    a = 1
    a = 1
    a = 1
    a = 1
```

In the output buffer it then prints:

```
>>> >>> >>> ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... >>>
```

which appears really slowly.

Another example, using:

`(process-send-string PROCESS "\n\n\n\n")`

is also slow, as well as `(comint-send-input)` after some lines are written in the inferior python shell.

It seems mostly enters are slowing this down.

Note that all of this is not the case in Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you add some code to make it clearer the interaction between the objects you're talking about?

Comment: @jhrf There's no code involved in the example, the act of evaluating any kind of text (some `def` gets written to the python buffer) that spans a few lines takes something like a second to evaluate. Though maybe this helps. Thanks for asking!

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861178/emacs-inferior-mode-python-shell-appears-lagged?rq=1 ?

Comment: @leoluk It's different in the sense that he is using the print function; I'm just "evaluating" a function. The function text then appears in the buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I'm now avoiding the problem by using IPython instead of Python 2.7. It has the `%paste` magic command that helps me solve the issue.